# Retrieving time series data from redis

Tags: redis, time-series

I'm storing aggregated time series data in a Redis sorted set. The members are the Unix timestamp being aggregated (say a year) and the scores are the number of events in that time frame. I get how to use ZINCRBY to update the keys, but how would I get a range out of the database? Would I have to use ZSCORE for every timestamp I wanted? Am I even reasoning about this correctly?

Comment: You can use `ZRANGE` or `ZRANGEBYSCORE` to retrieve a range by rank or by score, but there's no `ZRANGEBYMEMBER`; if you need to query by timestamp, I'd say you should use the timestamps as the score and keep the number of events as the member data; you can then replace your `ZINCRBY ` with a `ZADD`, both commands are O(log(n)). This should work if you don't need to query by the amount of events; if you do, then you'll have to mantain an additional structure to be able to query by timestamps aswell.

Comment: (Also, 1) with redis you usually design your data around your accessing needs and 2) using timestamps as the scores in a sorted set is a pretty common pattern, and pretty handy)

Comment: I thought about that but don't understand how to keep tack of the values in that situation. Unless there's a command to pop and put as an atomic operation there are bound to be race conditions, right?

Comment: You can use `MULTI` and `EXEC` to make the operation atomic and `WATCH` to avoid race conditions, see http://redis.io/topics/transactions, specially the section "Optimistic locking using check-and-set" which uses an example very similar to your case.

Comment: Although I don't think you can watch a specific sorted set member, but you could use a temporary key instead. For instance, for each transaction you watch and increase the key event:$timestamp with an expiration of one second, and increase the member of the sorted set within the transaction aswell. If the transaction fails because another client modified event:$timestamp then the member in the sorted set won't be updated. One thing to note though, if event:$timestamp expires and it's created again `WATCH` won't notice the change; but 1 second should be enough to prevent race conditions.